# Ant Regular expression, seperate a path into directory name and file name where file name has multiple dots

Tags: regex, ant

I am trying to extract the directory and file name from a path.
I have got it working with normal file names that only have a single dot as part of the extension name, but it fails to work if there are multiple dot's in the file name.

Normal case results in:

```
Web Content/javascript/more/andmore/evenmore AND uidoublerebel
```

I am wanting it to also handle a file name like:

```
ui.effects.core-1.7-doublerebel.js
```

results in:

```
Web Content/javascript/more/andmore/evenmore AND ui.effects.core-1.7-doublerebel
```

Can anyone help with the regular expression I have.

`${content.dir.unix}/([^\.]*)/([^\.]*)\.((css)|(js))$`

```
<property name="content.dir.path" value="C:/ajm/zip/jdw-content"/>

<property name="file.name.problem" value="C:/ajm/zip/jdw-content/Web Content/javascript/ore/andmore/evenmore/ui.effects.core-1.7-doublerebel.js"/>

<property name="file.name.works" value="C:/ajm/zip/jdw-content/Web Content/javascript/more/andmore/evenmore/uidoublerebel.js"/>

<propertyregex override="yes"
  property="zip.dir.structure"  input="${file.name.problem}"
  regexp="${content.dir.unix}/([^\.]*)/([^\.]*)\.((css)|(js))$" replace="\1 AND \2"/>
<echo> messge = ${zip.dir.structure}</echo>
```

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 4):

Ant has got [basename](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) and [dirname](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html) tasks that accomplish what you're looking for

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

    <property name="file.name.problem" value="Web Content/javascript/ore/andmore/evenmore/ui.effects.core-1.7-doublerebel.js"/

    <dirname property="file.dirname" file="${file.name.problem}"/>
    <basename property="file.basename" file="${file.name.problem}" suffix=".js"/>

    <target name="build">
        <echo>
        Original: ${file.name.problem}

        Dirname: ${file.dirname}
        Basename: ${file.basename}
        </echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ANT style regex, but I believe that if you replace [^.]* with just .*, your regex will succeeed. I.e. something like:

```
${content.dir.unix}/(.*)/(.*)\.((css)|(js))$
```

Br. Morten